# Quartz configuration for play framework

Tags: quartz-scheduler, playframework-2.1

I currently have a problem with quartz JDBC job store in play framework. Quartz reads its own properties file (I assumed through the common configuration interface). The problem is I'm not sure how this interaction is enabled in play framework.

I guess this question is also applicable to all other third party library using a configuration file.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.  Add details to help readers understand what you have tried, and what you expect to come from your question.

Comment: Thanks Randy for pointing that out ... first timer on stackoverflow ... didn't quite get the etiquette yet

 I was making the switch to store jobs in DB instead of the RAM, and that requires adding a property to the configuration file. My question was where do I declares quartz properties so that quartz is able to load the configuration ? I was trying to add the properties to application.conf but that doesn't seem to do the trick

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simply adding quartz.properties file into conf folder ... quartz will read that file for all configuration